# Why won't my JS created class appear on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the bootstrap class `alert alert-success` appear on the top of the page when the user successfully inputs the required fields upon hitting the `Submit` button.  I made numerous attempts at solving this but I feel like my current code in the `GeneralChecker()` function is pretty close (or not).  Below is the the `alert alert-success` I'm talking about (not including the text after `Success!`, I can do that myself later).  I should also mention that I'm not getting any errors in the console.

[image]

Here's the `gameTime.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>     
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="success"></div>
    </div> 


    <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
        <div id="allFields">
            <div class="moveUsername">
                <h1>(All numbers inputted will be assumed that it's in dollars)</h1>
                <label for="usr">What's your annual salary?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="What's your annual salary?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="ageMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend every month on bills?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="monthlyBills" name="ageChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend every month on bills?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="emailMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend when going out?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="goingOut" name="emailChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend when going out?" required="required">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the gameTime.js file

```
    function GeneralChecker(salary, fixedExpense, variableExpense) {
    var self = this;
    self.salary = salary;
    self.fixedExpense = fixedExpense;
    self.variableExpense = variableExpense;
    self.isSalaryZeroOrLess = function() {
        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
        console.log(this); 
        if(s <= 0) {
            console.log("Looks like you have no income!");
        } else {
            console.log("Your annual salary is: ", s);
        }
        self.monthlyBillChecker();
        self.monthlySalaryChecker();
    }
    self.successChecker = function() {
        if(self.monthlyBillChecker() && self.monthlySalaryChecker()) {
            var s = document.getElementById("success");
            s.className += " alert alert-success";
            document.body.appendChidl(s);
            document.write(s);
        }
    }
}

GeneralChecker.prototype.monthlySalaryChecker = function() {
    var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
    var userMonthlySalary = s / 12;
    console.log(userMonthlySalary);

    if(userMonthlySalary) {
        console.log("That means you make " + userMonthlySalary + " a month.");
    }
}

var fin = new GeneralChecker(1000, 1000, 1000);
document.querySelector("#btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess);
document.querySelector("#btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", fin.successChecker);

GeneralChecker.prototype.monthlyBillChecker = function() {
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyBills").value);

    if(m <= 0) {
        console.log("Looks like you have no monthly payments to make!");
    }
    if(isNaN(m)) {
        console.log("This isn't a number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: why?  you are using a submit button so the form will be submitted to fast to see the green banner for more than a flicker.

Comment: @Bindrid I want the green banner to appear after the user hits submit granted if everything they inputted in the fields are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here my updated answer:

Add in your `form`-Tag the attribute `onSubmit="checkData()"`.
After that, create a new function in your JS-File:

```
function checkData() {
    *here your whole code*
}
```

In this function, you can now do all the stuff you want. You can get the values of your input's with `document.getElementById("fieldId").value`. If you want to check the monthlySalary spearated like before, just add a new function like this one and call it within the checkData Function.

I hope this helps, tell me if you don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andy.  I've tried `onsubmit = "GeneralChecker()"` already before making this post, it didn't work :(.  I corrected the spelling mistakes but it still didn't work.

Comment: Then, I would check if the code gets executed until your `.appendChild()`-Function. I recommend you to use `console.log("foo")` at different positions to verify, that your code is executed like you want it to be.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're right.  `console.log("foo")` works anywhere except inside the  `if()` statement in `successChecker()`.  I can now conclude that the `successChecker()` function isn't working properly.

Comment: Ok, I reviewed your code and tried executing it. You have multiple logical problems here - I would recommend to use a simpler and (in my opinion) cleaner way. Is that okay for you? I would update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: When you wrote `*here your whole code*` do you mean place my entire `gameTime.js` file code inside the `checkData()` function so that I can proceed to do what I want?

Comment: Just copy the parts of your old code in your desired order in there. I.e., start with the part of the code which checks the input of the fields, after that, calculate the monthly salary or what you want. You can now just put code in there without andy function or objects like before. I would recommend to check every new codepart you insert and use console.log whenever you are not sure what value a variable has or if code gets executed or not.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The reason why I'm using prototypes is because I want to practice it.  This is my first "major" project using JS.  I just want this `alert alert-success` to work.

Comment: Oh, okay sorry, didn't know that. So then you should leave your old code like it was, just place the 3 lines where you define your object (var fin = etc.) in our `sendData()`-Function, so the object of your function just gets created when you click the button. You also replace the 1000's in the arguments list with the values of your input fields, that would be the correct way to instance `GeneralChecker()`, in with you can now use your salary, fixedExpense and variableExpense without reading the values out of the input fields. Please feedback me what happened now.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm gonna give that a shot.  I'll let you know if anything goes wrong.

Comment: I figured it out!  Now all I have to do is include `Success!` followed by a message.

Comment: Glad to hear that, much fun with your next programming steps :)

Comment: Yep, thanks for all your advice :D.  One last thing, I eventually want to get into Angular JS so it's right on my end to continue to learn vanilla Javascript, right (i.e. build projects of this nature)?  Is what I'm learning going to be outdated anytime soon?

Comment: I'm not really into Angular JS odr vanilla JS but I know that these libraries are the most used in the JS world so generally spoken, no, they won't be outdated. I also recommend you the jQuery library, cause it'll make your life much easier, probably easier than vanilla JS. But I think you should do some more small things with regular JS first to get used to the JS ways of working. But G

Comment: Sorry, I've not finished:) Generally spoken, using libraries is a good thing cause it saves you just code, not the requirement of knowledge. So go on and have fun! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `<button>` tag without a javascript callback. Try adding `<button onClick="GeneralChecker(..)">`

Comment: I was going to do that but I read recently that I should use `.addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`.  Maybe in this case it's good to use it?

Comment: Also, would go in between`onclick="GeneralChecker(..)`?  I've never placed a parameter inside an `onclick` function before.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean type = 'text'?

in any case, I think you would be better served by doing something like...

```
    var fin = new GeneralChecker(1000, 1000, 1000);
    $(function($){

        $("input[type='text']").on("change", function() {
            fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess();
            fin.successChecker();
        });
    });
```

This way the required fields will be checked after each change and the user will be told once the form is ready instead of waiting for the button to be clicked.